# Combine two linux command to show as single string

Tags: linux, shell

I am having two commands

`hostname -f` and `cat /sys/block/sda/size`

Need to combined output like `hostname:34345`

I tried using

```
hostname -f && cat /sys/block/sda/size
```

But output is printing in two lines. Please help me to get the output as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the `bash` shell, you can use [command substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html):

```
echo "$(hostname):$(cat /sys/block/sda/size)"
```